# Google sheet change cell type based on another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'll try to explain it

on B2 i got values like ( valid proof, invalid proof, no proof ) i need C2 to change from text to a checkbox if B2 value was " valid proof "

any thoughts ?

i tried to make a conditional formatting and do it with a formula but couldn't find any

Comment: So, there's text in C2 as well? What text is in there? Or are you saying that you simply want C2 to be checked if B2 has "valid proof" in it, and C2 to remain unchecked if B2 has "invalid proof" or "no proof"?

Comment: the C2 is empty to add a manual input for all other reasons than valid proofs

but only at valid proof i need to add this checkbox to make sure that user is uploaded his proof

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong... When B2 changes to "valid proof", you want to insert a checkbox in C2. And presumably this also applies to every row of Column B/C, not just row#2.

Comment: `i tried to make a conditional formatting and do it with a formula but couldn't find any` You are quite right. This can't be done with a conventional formula. You will need to write an apps script using Event Objects, and an `onEdit` trigger to detect the value in cell B2. There are many precedents that you can research on this.

Comment: you're right @Tedinoz with some big search this was created and i can say it was really helpful

Comment: Glad you found a solution, and for posting it as an answer - "paying it forward" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
function onEdit(e) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sName = sheet.getName();
  if (sName === "June")
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 6) {
    if (e.value === "valid proof")
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),10).insertCheckboxes();
    else
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),10).removeCheckboxes();
  }
}
```